# Missing ; error in first attempt at script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing an OnOpen script for a spreadsheet.
I have a number in cell B1 and a date in C1
When the spreadsheet is opened, I want to check that the date on the sheet is today's and if not, it will change the sheet's date and also reset the number in B1 to 0

I am getting the error Missing ; before statement. (line 8, file "Code")
(Which is the If Statement)

```
function OnOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Create Ticket");
  var TicketCount = sheet.getRange("B1").getvalue();
  var TicketDate = sheet.getRange("C1").getvalue();
  var Today = date().setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

  If not TicketDate = Today {
    sheet.getRange("C1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    sheet.getRange("B1").setvalue(0);
  }
}
```

This is all new to me so my apologies if this is basic.  The only coding I ever did was simple VBA, so I don't even know what == means.

Comment: try replacing `If not TicketDate = Today` with `if(TicketDate != Today)`

Comment: That got it, so does != mean not equal to?  Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Create Ticket");
  var TicketCount = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var TicketDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange("C1").getValue()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy");
  var Today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy");
  if(TicketDate != Today) {
    sheet.getRange("C1").setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy"));
    sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(0);
  }
}
```

Be carefull because in your code there is some typo error.
setvalue => setValue
getvalue => getValue

This will generate error.

To format date you can use Utilities.formatDate()

Stéphane

Comment: You're a star Steph.  The code is falling down on the last line (trying to get number 0 into cell), but I would never have found that date formatting on my own.  Thank you!

Comment: That's because I was changing the typo's and I changed it to SetValue instead of setValue.  Thanks again for the help.